# How can I send a specific action from a component based on some conditions?

Tags: ember.js

I am extending `Ember.TextField` (which extends `Ember.Component`) in order to read a file. My intent is if the chosen file satisfies some conditions, send an action to the controller. But if it fails, send a different action. However when I try to do this, no action is called.

I created a **[jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tonorida/6/)** of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send in what the action should map to in that scope when you create the component, in your case they are the same action name, but in other cases, the component could be calling `acceptChanges` and it could be hitting the controller action `acceptImageChanges` where-as another may be `acceptDocumentChanges`.  This allows you to use the component multiple times in the same scope, yet have the actions that are passed out of it be customized per instance.

```
{{view App.ImportFileView invalidFileType='invalidFileType' acceptChanges='acceptChanges' }}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tonorida/10/edit